# How to cast varchar to MAP(VARCHAR,VARCHAR) in presto

Tags: cassandra, presto, trino

I have table in presto, one column named ("mappings") have key-value pair as string

select mappings from hello;

Ex: {"foo": "baar", "foo1": "bar1" }

I want to cast "mappings" column into a MAP

like select CAST("mappings" as MAP) from hello;

This will throw error in presto. How can we translate this to map?

Answer (score 18):

There is no canonical string representation for a `MAP` in Presto/Trino, so so there's no way to cast it directly to `MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR)`. But, if your string contains a JSON map, you can use the [`json_parse`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse) function to convert the string into a value of `JSON` type and convert that to a SQL `MAP` via a [cast](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#cast-from-json).

Example:

```sql
WITH
data(c) AS (
    VALUES '{"foo": "baar", "foo1": "bar1"}'
),
parsed AS (
    SELECT cast(json_parse(c) as map(varchar, varchar)) AS m
    FROM data
)
SELECT m['foo'], m['foo1']
FROM parsed
```

produces:

```
 _col0 | _col1
-------+-------
 baar  | bar1
```

Answer (score 1):

`select cast( json_parse(mappings) as MAP(VARCHAR,VARCHAR)) from hello1;`