# Parse JSON from Presto varchar column fails

Tags: presto

I am attempting to convert my `varchar` column data, which is stringifed `JSON`, to `MAP` datatype so I can reference the data as elements.

```sql
WITH
data(c) AS (
    SELECT message from mydb.mytable
),
parsed AS (
    SELECT cast(json_parse(c) as map(varchar, varchar)) AS m
    FROM data
)
SELECT m['action'], m['uuid']
FROM parsed
```

Sample data looks like:
`{"action":"send","timestamp":1566432054,"uuid":"1234"}`

I tried solution provided here: [How to cast varchar to MAP(VARCHAR,VARCHAR) in presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55279784/how-to-cast-varchar-to-mapvarchar-varchar-in-presto), which is where I got the query from replacing `values` with a `select` statement but it did not work. I get error:

`INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to map(varchar,varchar)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`json_parse`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse) + `cast` work on your example data:

```
SELECT CAST(json_parse(str) AS map(varchar, varchar))
FROM (VALUES '{"action":"send","timestamp":1566432054,"uuid":"1234"}') t(str);
```

I tested this on Presto 317:

```
presto> SELECT CAST(json_parse(str) AS map(varchar, varchar))
     -> FROM (VALUES '{"action":"send","timestamp":1566432054,"uuid":"1234"}') t(str);
                     _col0
------------------------------------------------
 {action=send, uuid=1234, timestamp=1566432054}
(1 row)
```

My guess is that some data row is different than your example and this data row cannot be `cast`. You can find it with [`try`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try):

```
SELECT str
FROM your_table
WHERE str IS NOT NULL
AND try(CAST(json_parse(str) AS map(varchar, varchar))) IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yes, you are 100% correct. The data is not always parsable as JSON nor "castable" to Map(varchar, vachar). I am going to be using `try` a lot more now. Many thanks for the education ;)

Comment: You're welcome. You might also want to join Presto Community Slack (https://prestosql.io/community.html) where you can get more help (also in case which do fit in Q&A format of SO).